# How to use self join to filter the records in same table in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table which has both employees and team leaders.
I have below data

```
Declare @EMP AS TABLE(EmpID INT, EmpName VARCHAR(100),TeamLeadID INT)
INSERT INTO @EMP(EmpID, EmpName,TeamLeadID) VALUES
 (1,'Ramesh',5)
,(2,'Mahesh',3)
,(3,'Vijay',3)
,(4,'Varma',5)
,(5,'Raj',5)
```

I want to list all employees along with thier teamleaderid and name. But the teamleaderid and name should be blank when the employeeid = teamleadid.

The result should be as follows.

```
EmpID   EmpName   TeamLeadID    TeamLeadName
1       Ramesh        5             Raj
2       Mahesh        3            Vijay
3       Vijay        NULL           NULL
4       Varma         5             Raj
5        Raj         NULL           NULL
```

The code is as below.

```
SELECT E.EmpID,E.EmpName,TL.TeamLeadID,TL.EmpName AS TeamLeadName 
FROM @Emp E
LEFT JOIN @Emp TL ON E.TeamLeadID = TL.EmpID AND E.EmpID ! = TL.EmpID
```

Is there any other way of rewriting this code with much performance (Mainly without using `Not equal to at E.EmpID ! = TL.EmpID`) and without using CTE?

Comment: Seems like you should be fixing your data. Someone can't be their own leader, so user `3` shouldn't have a value of `3` for `TeamLeadID`; it should be `NULL`.

Comment: FYI, in your sample data, all your employees have the name `'Ramesh'`. Where did `'Vijay'`', `'Varma'`, etc, come from?

Comment: Why impose conditions such as don't use `!=` and CTE? Both of those are important tools in your T-SQL toolbox, and neither are in and of themselves bad for performance. in SQL you should solve your problem correctly using the correct tools, and only then, if performance is an issue, should you try and tweak the way you do it.

Comment: @Larnu, Sorry the data is corrected

Comment: I've corrected your sample data based on the expected results.

Comment: Are you having performance problems with the current query? What does the execution plan look like? Please use [Paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) to share it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid the NOT EQUAL in the WHERE clause, you can move your "logic" in the SELECT clause like this:

```
SELECT E.EmpID,E.EmpName, 
      IIF(TL.TeamLeadID=E.EmpID,NULL,TL.TeamLeadID) AS TeamLeadID ,
      IIF(TL.EmpName=E.EmpName,NULL,TL.EmpName) AS TeamLeadName
FROM @Emp E
LEFT JOIN @Emp TL ON E.TeamLeadID = TL.EmpID
```

Whether it will be more performant is difficult to say. It depends on your data, and mostly affected records and number of teamleaders. Difference should be ridiculous if you don't have huge volumes

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use CASE WHEN clause in SELECT statement

```
SELECT E.EmpID,E.EmpName,
CASE
    WHEN E.EmpID = TL.TeamLeadID
        THEN NULL
    ELSE TL.TeamLeadID
END AS TeamLeadID
,CASE
    WHEN E.EmpID = TL.TeamLeadID
        THEN NULL
    ELSE TL.EmpName
END AS TeamLeadName 
FROM @Emp E
LEFT JOIN @Emp TL ON E.TeamLeadID = TL.EmpID
```